# Mixing different Enums sharing the same interface in a collection

Tags: inheritance, enums, kotlin

For some reason, Kotlin evaluates the following expression as `List` of `Any` instead of `Animal`, how can I make this happen?

.

```
interface Animal
enum class Dog:Animal{
   WHITE;
}
enum class Cat:Animal{
   BLACK;
}
.............

fun loadAnimals(names:List<String>):List<???>{
    return names.map{
       when (/*some cond*/) {
        true -> Cat.Black
        else -> Dog.White
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: I'd think `List<Animal>` or `List<out Animal>` should work

Comment: @EpicPandaForce nope, it really wants List<Any>

Comment: Interestingly, you can force it to realize its problems by adding `as Animal` after either animal you are returning. The IDE will say it is an unused cast, but it is not

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah i know casting works, but I still find it weird that the tree compiler generates does not see that

Comment: `names.map<String, Animal>` also works.

Comment: @yegodm yep, it does! Thanks - this way is nicer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the compiler supposed to infer that it is a list of Animal? What if `Dog` also implements `Canine` interface? What if Cat and Dog both also implement `Carnivore` interface?

If you want to return a list of `Animal` you need to cast your return values in this case.

```
fun loadAnimals(names: List<String>): List<Animal> {
    return names.map {
        when (/*some cond*/) {
            true -> Cat.Black as Animal
            else -> Dog.White as Animal
        }
    }
}
```

or like this, without casting:

```
fun loadAnimals(names: List<String>): List<Animal> {
    return names.map<String, Animal> {
        when (/*some cond*/) {
            true -> Cat.BLACK
            else -> Dog.WHITE
        }
    }
}
```